# Correct use of signals in an activity diagram

Tags: android-activity, uml, signals, diagram

I have a question regarding activity diagrams. I read a lot of materials on the topic but to be honest, I am still not sure about the signal sending and receiving.

I did a simple activity diagram for the password authentication.

Basically what I want to do is to send a message to the client after the server performs a search in the database. Is this use of signals correct?

Any criticism toward the structure of the diagram will be welcomed.

Here is the mentioned diagram:

[image]

Comment: The problem I have with this activity diagram is that is very close to the current implementation. What if you decide to ask for an email address and captcha instead of an id? What if you will not encrypt the password, but use encrypted data transmission instead? What if you will not send a message after a successful authentication, but redirect the user to a requested page? The current diagram is not abstract enough imo.

Answer (score 0):

Signals are used to indicate a communication to some entity external to the system considered (e.g., an e-mail to a customer). So it depends on which are the borders of your system: are the client and the server part of separate systems from the viewpoint of this activity?

Signals are also somehow used to indicate an asynchronous communication. In this case I would not use signals: in my opinions these are actions. Maybe you can add the object transferred (the data in this case) in the diagram if you think it is useful but I would avoid a signal.